# Python, Selenium: how to click on javascript:void(0) element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have an "onclick" element in a webpage,

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick=
    "toIndexHtml('3','http://xxxxxxxxxxx/trade','0')">
<i></i>
<span></span>
trade
</a>
```

It is shown in the webpage as a button and I want to click on it, I tried to search for it using the following code:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'toIndexHtml')]").click()
```

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div/ul/li[3]/a"))).click()
```

Both are not working, please suggest if there is any other ways! Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I am using Chrome WebDriver and Chrome v64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first locator looks perfect and should have worked.

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick^='toIndexHtml']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@onclick,'toIndexHtml')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks! just figured out my element is in an iframe that I need to switch to that frame before locating it:)

Comment: @lambda COuld you explain a bit more? I have the same problem, and the answer above won't work?